# How to get every nth number in array? Not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I need to separate the first three numberss and then the fourth to “separate them”.
Finally, the code should look like:

the first three numbers: 1,1,1fourth number: 2

the first three numbers: 3,3,3fourth number: 4

```
var numb = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
var numb, text, fLen, i;
fLen = numb.length;

text = for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "the first three numbers:" + numb[i] + "fourth number:"+ numb[i] +"<br>";
  }

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = text;
```

```
<div id="text">1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take different names as the `id` of html elements, because browsers take this name as variable for htis element. This is not relyable to use.

Take the string and split it by comma and possible following white space and iterate as long as the index is smaller than the length of the array.

Inside take three items from the array as first part and another as the fourth part.

```js
var html = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML,
    values = html.split(/,\s*/),
    result = '',
    i = 0;

while (i < values.length) {
    result += "the first three numbers:" + values.slice(i, i += 3).join(', ');
    result += " fourth number: "+ values[i++] + "<br>";
}

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="text">1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was quick and easy for you. What I want to achieve is to extract a value into each variable in gradient color. I asked the question asm the day before, and I didn't find it anywhere on the internet. The goal is to dynamically change an already existing gradient. This is the link to the question and I would be very grateful if you could help. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61887798/how-to-separate-and-combine-each-value-in-the-gradient

Answer (score 1):

I would use lodash for this.

Edited to be done without lodash.

```
<html>
    <div id="text">1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4</div>
</html>

<script>
    var numb = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.split(/,\s*/);
    console.log(numb)
    var chunk_array = []
    var i,j,temparray,chunk = 4;
    for (i=0,j=numb.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
            temparray = numb.slice(i,i+chunk);
            chunk_array.push(temparray)
    }
    console.log(chunk_array)
    result =''
    chunk_array.forEach(element => result += "the first three numbers:" + element.slice(0,2).join(', ') + " fourth element: " + element[3] + "<br/>")
    console.log(result)
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

Comment: The inclusion of a whole library is maybe overkill for this simple problem.
A simple if with modulo on the index should do the trick ?